# CRM for a web host

Tags: python, django

I wrote an application which runs correctly, but I just want to have some feedback on it. Is there something unnecessary, or could there be something more pythonic, or did I write some code which Django could cover in particular cases?

**views.py**

```
from program.models import contract, cert, user, rdp, server
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from collections import defaultdict 

# delivers a json object with several informations
def q(request):
        # parameter given by url
        param_hash = request.GET.get('hash', '')

        contract_list = get_user_contract(param_hash)

        servers = []
        server_name = []
        server_url = []
        rdplst = []
        certs = []

        if contract_list:
                # get required lists
                servers = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'servers')
                server_name = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'server_name')
                server_url = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'server_url')
                rdplst = get_info(contract_list, rdp, 'rdp')
                certs = get_info(servers, cert, 'cert')

        if not contract_list:
                return HttpResponse('404 Not Found')

        return JsonResponse(build_dict(server_name, server_url, rdplst, certs))

# gets the contract number of a specific user
def get_user_contract(param_hash):
        contract_list = []

        for iter_user in user.objects.all():
                if iter_user.hashed == param_hash:
                        for iterator in iter_user.contract.all():
                                contract_list.append(iterator.number)

        if contract_list:
                return contract_list
        if not contract_list:
                return None

# gets the available servers for a specific user
def get_info(passed_list, modelname, wanted_info):
        some_list = []

        #print('0 ' + wanted_info)

        for info in passed_list:
                #print(passed_list)
                #print('1 ' + wanted_info)
                for iterator in modelname.objects.all():
                        #print('2 ' + wanted_info)
                        if wanted_info == 'rdp':
                                if iterator.contract.number == info:
                                        some_list.append(iterator.config)

                        elif wanted_info == 'servers':
                                if iterator.number == info:
                                        some_list.append(iterator.server)

                        elif wanted_info == 'server_url':
                                if iterator.number == info:
                                        some_list.append(iterator.server.url)

                        elif wanted_info == 'server_name':
                                if iterator.number == info:
                                        some_list.append(iterator.server.name)

                        elif wanted_info == 'cert':
                                if iterator.server == info:
                                        some_list.append(iterator.url)

        if some_list:
                return some_list

        elif not some_list:
                return None

# builds a json object with a list of servernames, rdp config files and urls to the ssl certificates
def build_dict(server_name, server_url, rdp, cert):
        json_dict = defaultdict(list)

        if server_name and server_url:
                for i, iter_name in enumerate(server_name):
                        server_dict = dict( name = iter_name, url = server_url[i] )
                        json_dict['server'].append(server_dict)
        if rdp:
                for iter_rdp in rdp:
                        json_dict['config'].append(iter_rdp)
        if cert:
                for iter_cert in cert:
                        json_dict['cert'].append(iter_cert)

        return json_dict
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class server(models.Model):
        name = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Servername')
        url = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'URL')

        def __unicode__(self):
                return u'%s' % (self.name)

        class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Server"
                verbose_name_plural = "Server"

class contract(models.Model):
        server = models.ForeignKey(server, verbose_name = "Server")
        number = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Vertragsnummer des Kunden', unique = True, max_length = 64)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return u'%s' % (self.number)

        class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Vertragsnummer"
                verbose_name_plural = "Vertragsnummern"

class user(models.Model):
        contract = models.ManyToManyField(contract, verbose_name = "Vertragsnummer")
        # Kommen von der Anwendung
        hashed = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Hash des Usernamen')

        def __unicode__(self):
                return u'%s' % (self.hashed)

        class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Benutzer"
                verbose_name_plural = "Benutzer"

class rdp(models.Model):
        contract = models.ForeignKey(contract, verbose_name = "Vertragsnummer")
        config = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Liste der RDP config Files')

        def __unicode__(self):
                return u'%s' % (self.config)

        class Meta:
                verbose_name = "RDP Config File"
                verbose_name_plural = "RDP Config Files"

class cert(models.Model):
        server = models.ForeignKey(server, verbose_name = "Server")
        name = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Name des SSL Zertifikats')
        url = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Url des SSL Zertifikats')

        def __unicode__(self):
                return u'%s' % (self.name)

        class Meta:
                verbose_name = "SSL Zertifikat"
                verbose_name_plural = "SSL Zertifikate"
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from program import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^q$', views.q, name='q')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Logic**

You could rewrite `q` with an `else` :

```
    if contract_list:
            # get required lists
            servers = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'servers')
            server_name = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'server_name')
            server_url = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'server_url')
            rdplst = get_info(contract_list, rdp, 'rdp')
            certs = get_info(servers, cert, 'cert')
    else:
            return HttpResponse('404 Not Found')

    return JsonResponse(build_dict(server_name, server_url, rdplst, certs))
```

Then, you realise you can actualy move the last return closer to where it belongs :

```
    if contract_list:
            # get required lists
            servers = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'servers')
            server_name = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'server_name')
            server_url = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'server_url')
            rdplst = get_info(contract_list, rdp, 'rdp')
            certs = get_info(servers, cert, 'cert')
            return JsonResponse(build_dict(server_name, server_url, rdplst, certs))
     return HttpResponse('404 Not Found')
```

Also, you do not need to define the variables before. Actually, it is better to define things only when you really need it.

Thus, the function can be written :

```
def q(request):
        # parameter given by url
        param_hash = request.GET.get('hash', '')
        contract_list = get_user_contract(param_hash)

        if contract_list:
                # get required lists
                servers = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'servers')
                server_name = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'server_name')
                server_url = get_info(contract_list, contract, 'server_url')
                rdplst = get_info(contract_list, rdp, 'rdp')
                certs = get_info(servers, cert, 'cert')
                return JsonResponse(build_dict(server_name, server_url, rdplst, certs))
        return HttpResponse('404 Not Found')
```

The same kind of idea applies to `get_user_contract` and you can write it :

```
    if contract_list:
            return contract_list
    else:
            return None
```

which can be reduced in a simple :

```
    return contract_list if contract_list else None
```

However, as the function name implies that it will return a list, I think it is probably better to return an empty string than `None`.

And again, the same thing applies to `get_info`.

Comment: There is still a lot to improve but I do not know much about Djando.